Optimal Structure Optimization Strategies for Aliovalent Doping
I hope this message finds you well. I am a beginner in performing DFT calculations using VASP and am currently researching aliovalent doping in solid electrolytes. My study involves substituting certain elements in the structure with aliovalent dopants and adjusting lithium (Li) distribution to maintain charge neutrality.
I am evaluating two primary methods for structure optimization post-doping and Li redistribution, both starting from an already optimized base structure:
Method 1:

Doping: Substitute target atoms with aliovalent dopants.
Li Redistribution: Remove all Li atoms and redistribute the desired number of Li ions.
Optimization: Perform a single structure optimization on the doped and Li-rearranged structure.

Method 2:

Doping: Substitute target atoms with aliovalent dopants in the optimized Li-containing structure.
Initial Optimization: Optimize the doped structure to stabilize changes from doping.
Li Redistribution: Remove all Li atoms and redistribute them.
Final Optimization: Perform a final structure optimization on the Li-rearranged structure.

Given the multiple substitution configurations involved, I am concerned about the computational cost associated with Method 2, which requires optimizing each structure twice. Additionally, I worry that selecting only the lowest-energy doped structures before Li redistribution might overlook more stable configurations after Li addition.
How significant are the differences in final optimized structures and their energies between Method 1 and Method 2?
Thank you very much for your time and assistance!
